# PHP MVC render view method

Tags: php, mvc

I am working on creating a simple MVC inspired framework (for learning purposes and because i don't want to use a pre-existing framework at the moment). I have the system already set up and its working as it should, but i would like to have some feedback on the "view" part of the system, maybe i have set it up in a way that will prove to be inefficient in the future if the app grows, and maybe there is just a better way of doing what i am doing.

**A little bit about how i set up the "framework":**

When a user goes to a url, for example /posts/post_id, the file that is loaded is index.php, this file instantiates a router file, the router instantiates the required controller (and method if set) based on the url.
The controller works with the relevant model to get data from the database (in this example, the post data), and then the controller sends that data off to the view class. The controller also sends the "view settings" to the view class.

**What i mean by view settings and my use of it and view data:**

The way i have set up the "View" part of this system is to be able to render either an entire page, which includes the template (header, footer, sidebar, etc.), or to render just a single html file (without the header, footer, etc.).

To do this, i send from the controller to the view class the following settings:

1. The view settings - what navigation menu to show, if to show a sidebar and its location on the page (left, right, none), if to render just a file with html without the whole template (e.g. just a post, or a form), or a whole page with the template.
2. The view data - the actual data needed for the view, for example the post data.

```
class View{

    /*  $viewData is sent from the controller, it contains all of the data needed
    *   for the view, including what i call the "view settings" as described above */
    public function __construct($viewData){

        //Instantiate a new error for this view (error handling class)
        $this->err = new ErrorClass(get_class($this));

        //Instantiate a new helper (helper functions used in the view)
        $this->helpers = new ViewHelpers();

        /* Save variables from the $viewData array */

        //If a single file was sent to render (receives the file name and is rendered later)
        $this->viewFile     = $viewData['view_file'];

        //If a whole page was sent to be rendered (this will render the whole template also)
        $this->viewName     = $viewData['view_name'];

        //Template data, only used if a whole page should be rendered
        $this->templateData = $viewData['template_data'];

        //The data for the view, e.g. post data
        $this->viewData     = $viewData['view_data'];

        //Call the render view method
        $this->renderView();
    }



    /* Function to render the view output
    ===============================================*/
    private function renderView(){

        //If a single file should be rendered
        if($this->viewFile && file_exists(VIEWS_PATH.$this->viewFile)){
            require(VIEWS_PATH.$this->viewFile);


        //If a whole page should be rendered
        }elseif($this->viewName && file_exists(TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH)){
            require(TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH);


        //Save an error
        }else{
            echo 'Oops, something went wrong, we are looking into it!';
            $this->err->setError(array('err_cat' => 3, 'err_msg' => "View wasn't able to load"));
        }
    }
}
```

**A note about `VIEWS_PATH` and `TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH`:**

`VIEWS_PATH` is the path to the folder that contains all of the html files, when i use `require(VIEWS_PATH.$this->viewFile);` i am including the file name that was sent from the controller, so this line would be: `require('/app/views/post_form.php');` for example.

`TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH` is a constant that equals the path to a main template file, what i mean by this is `TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH` = `/public/template/template.php`, and this file includes in it the header, the footer, and the actual main page that is needed, for example if loading a post form, the page would include the header, then the post form file, and then the footer.

EDIT:
I understand that my initial question was not very clear, so i edited it, hopefully this is clearer.

Comment: Hello again, by coincidence. Unfortunately it's not clear what you understand by _view_ and by _template_. This phrase is confusing: _" load either a single file, or an actual view through including the template"_. Also, in the 1st `elseif` statement, how is `$this->viewName` related to `TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH`? Maybe some value examples for the variables will make the whole picture clearer. And the constructor, it would be of much help to post it too.

Comment: A _view_ should be a class, like `UI\Web\View\Users\AddUser` or `UI\Web\View\Users\ListUsers`. This class should be able to _load_ and _render_ a certain template file, like `<project-root>/web/src/templates/templates/Users/add-user.html.twig` or `<project-root>/web/src/templates/templates/Users/list-users.html.twig`. So, a specific controller would call the `render()` method of a specific _view_ instance, which will _load_ and _render_ a specific template file. To remember is, that a _view_ should not be confused with a _template file_ (or, short, _template_).

Comment: P.S: The `.twig` extension denotes the fact that a _template engine_ (like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/)) can be used, in order to render the template files. In such a case, an instance of it would be injected into the specific _view_ object.

Comment: @dakis Please only seek clarification via comments.  Please post "review" advice as an answer.  Future researchers will not expect to see bits of review in comments under the question.  Please adhere to the simple/clear design of this site when posting.

Comment: @mickmackusa I will, thanks for the advice. Tried to give K.D a direction for her/his eventual question edits. Then I will transfer my previous two comments to an eventual answer, or remove them.

Comment: I don't really understand the difference between "a single file or an actual view". Anyone to explain?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, i edited my question and added the full code of the view class, hopefully its clearer now

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes i understand now that the way i said it is confusing because only i know what i mean :) Basically, i use ajax with this system, so i want to have the option to load a single html file, which could either be just a post form or something else that is just html, and i want to have the option to load an entire page, which will include the header, the footer, the sidebar, and anything else that is part of the apps template/theme. So by single file i mean an html file without the whole template/theme, and actual view i mean the whole page with the template.

Comment: @dakis Hey! Thanks, the relation between `$this->viewName` and `TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH` is that `TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH` is the path to the file that is used as the websites main template/theme, this file includes the header, the footer, and anything else needed by the theme (html only), and `$this->viewName` is a setting that is sent from the controller, which basically tells the template file which html file to include, so if for example im viewing the url /post/form/, the whole template/theme will load, the the template file will include the file `/app/views/post_form.php`

Comment: Which means that the template file would look something like this: `include("/public/template/header.php"); include("/app/view/post_form.php"); include("/public/template/footer.php");`  - the second include is what changes based on the page that is being viewed, so that could change to `include("/app/views/post_list.php");` for example

Comment: @dakis "A view should be a class" - do you mean that for every view that i load, for example `/post/form` i should have a view class file for it? from what i understand it would be `/app/views/post_form.php` which would be a class, and this class would render: `/public/template/post_form.php`, do i understand correctly?

Comment: And if so, what would be the need to create a new view class file for each view instead of using one view class file to load different view template files?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using, KD? And an upvote from me for your effort to provide us a lot of new informations.

Comment: i'm using version 7.3

Comment: Still it is not clear how does TEMPLATE_FILE_PATH file know whether to include /app/views/post_list.php or /app/view/post_form.php

Comment: Given the amount of clarifications requested, I consider this question off topic.

Comment: It knows based on the variable `$this->viewName`, that variable is either empty, or it equals a file name that the template should include. So if that variable is not empty, then the script knows it should include the template file, and the template file includes what ever file name is saved in `$this->viewName`

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I am not sure whether this question is on topic. There is literally only a handful lines of code, just a single conditional operator. With so much (as architecture, intentions, the desired goal) left out. But well.

I have but two suggestions.

1. **Use Twig.** It will solve ALL your problems at once.

   - Twig supports *template inheritance*. This is an enormously helpful feature, in your case it will let a particular template to decide whether to include the main site template or not. As a result, no need to mingle with viewName, viewFile, viewAnything. Just call a template, that's all.
   - The main template will be a single file instead of a bunch of separate "header, footer, sidebar... whatever" files, which helps editing a lot.
   - Twig supports blocks as well, so again you can move your sidebar around in every other template.
2. Error reporting. The current approach is flawed. In how many places you are going to add that `echo 'Oops, something went wrong, we are looking into it!';`? and what if you some day will decide to add some HTML to it? Or what if a client will expect JSON-formatted error, not a plain text? Instead of that clumsy echo with an error class combination you should really use an *error/exception handler*. In case a file is not found, an error will be raised, then your handler will intercept it, and then, in the handler, you are free to echo any text and use whatever logging method which pleases you. All in a single place. As a result, you will have

   - less code to write
   - centralized error processing
   - the more informative error message (the filesystem will tell you the exact reason instead of your generic "View wasn't able to load").

for more information see my article on the [principles of PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).

Comment: Thanks for the input! About the error reporting - i do actually have an error reporting class that i wrote, it may not be perfect as i am still learning this and working on it, but it is pretty dynamic and for the moment, set up in a way that works as i need it to, but of course can be improved (a lot!). The `echo` in the code i wrote is not part of the error class, that echo is more of a temporary thing to show that the requested file was not found, so that is something that will change.

Comment: As for using Twig, at this point i am trying to learn all i can about creating this whole type of system from scratch, not using any engines, frameworks, or anything else. So i would much prefer to understand the logic behind how it works and try to write my own code for it, rather than using something already made. From what i understand you say that Twig is set up in a way that the template file knows what to include? Does that mean that this file receives a variable or some sort of data, indicating what it should show on the page?

Comment: it is simply written in the template itself. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html

Comment: And if i don't want to include a whole page that includes header, footer, etc. and just include a file containing a form, or some other html, it would just be a matter of including that file rather than the full page template file no?

Comment: you just dont add extends keyword

Comment: ok, i see, but what if its a file that is used in both cases? What i mean is, you have a file that only has a form in it, call it `form.php`. What if you want to have the option to: A. Load that form with ajax, without the full template (header, footer, etc.), and B: load a url `posts/form/`, this url would include the header, footer, etc. and the actual `form.php` file. How can that be done?

Comment: I would say that your architecture is very untidy if you need that. I even forgot the time when my ajax calls returned HTML. For many years if not decades it's json only. but if you need that, make a wrapper file in twig that consists of two lines, one is extend to include the main template and one is include to load the form.

Comment: Interesting, how would you go about rendering a form with ajax then if your ajax returns json?

Comment: It's hard to answer without a context. Most of time all forms are already on the page since the pageload, you just unhide them when needed.

Comment: Ok, say we have a comment, and when we click on edit, it will load the comment form with the comments data in it, how would that be loaded? At the moment i just load the comment_form.php file with the comments data in place of the actual comment. Clicking save will reload the actual comment in place of the form.

Comment: We are writing comments here **right now** mind you. All forms are **preloaded** on the page. That's how. I suppose you need to learn some AJAX to clear your confusion. But it went already way too far from the initial issue. So I would recommend to ask a question on SO regarding your confusion about reloading.

Comment: right, ok, ill do some more research in to this. I don't want to use Twig right now because i want to create it all my self (not to reinvent the wheel, but to learn), but ill look at the concept of that and others, i do think that my current architecture is not as efficient as it should be at this point so this is all a work in progress. Thanks for the input!